# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

im trying to get proxies out of a web page

```
import urllib
import re
myfile = open("C:\\Users\Teli\Desktop\pro.txt", "w")
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm").read()
a = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', page)
myfile.write(str(a))
myfile.close()
```

why does it say:

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm").read()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using Python 2?

Comment: im sure im using python2.7

Comment: What does `print(__import__('sys').version)` output?

Comment: i dont have that in my code

Comment: Add it in and post what it outputs.

Comment: you were write i used python3 i fixed it im sorry i cant give a vote i only have 5 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used python2.7 and it worked

```
import urllib
import re
myfile = open("C:\\Users\Teli\Desktop\pro.txt", "w")
pagea = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm").read()
a = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', pagea)
pageb = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-02.htm").read()
b = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', pageb)
pagec = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-03.htm").read()
c = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', pagec)
paged = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-04.htm").read()
d = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', paged)
myfile.write(str(a)) myfile.write(str(b)) myfile.write(str(c))
myfile.write(str(d)) myfile.close()
```

Comment: huh. Pavel's answer precisely describes your problem and yet you decided not to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are either using python 3 or have a file named `urllib.py` in the current directory.

Comment: i havent used python 3 its python 2.7